# How to set in-params with their occurrences to jdbcTemplate query function?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I trying to execute a big SQL queries which can contain a several identical IN params, for example, {arg1, arg2, arg1, arg1, arg2}. Using jdbcTemplate I can execute query as below:

```
jdbcTemaplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object[] {arg1, arg2, arg1, arg1, arg2}, rowMap);
```

But in some queries the count of arguments can be large, so, writing simillar arguments like {arg, arg1, arg1, arg2, arg1, arg1, arg1, ...} looks awful. Is there any way to define set of indexes of occurrences for each in-param and send it to jdbcTemplate's query function? For example,

```
 ParamsOccurrences[] paramsOccurrences = {
     new ParamsOccurrences(arg1, new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 6 }),
     new ParamsOccurrences(arg2, new int[] { 2, 3 }) };

 jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, paramsOccurrences, rowMap);
```

I using Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found suitable solution for me. The simple way is to use **PreparedStatementSetter** parameter in jdbcTemplate's query function. Example:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {                    
                 preparedStatement.setObject(1, arg1); //example for arg1
                 preparedStatement.setObject(2, arg1);
                 ... //inside this method I just process every argument by setting specific numbers of occurrences in cycle
                }
            }, rowMap);
```